# Opencart / PHP multiple actions with data-toggle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart

I'm currently using Opencart which has a form in currency.tpl that changes the currency value depending on the button clicked.

The forms action works off of currency.php, there is then a button within the form that works as a drop down using data-toggle which allows the user to see the currencies available:

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-currency">

    <button class="buttoninvis" style="font-size:14px; margin-top:-4px;" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <?php echo $text_currency; ?></button>
```

My problem is that I am trying to have more than one action with a data-toggle button (which doesn't seem possible), the button which is currently opening a drop down menu, I would like it to still do this but also have another action which redirects to a different page when the button is clicked and the screen width is below X.

I have tried onclick, css displays, giving the button an ID and adding functions to detect the button click, etc but nothing works I'm not sure if it is to do with the form's action prohibiting it or the data toggle can only have one action?

Any help or ideas around this?

Comment: Does the toggle call an AJAX function?

Comment: No I don't believe so, I think that the form tries to redirect on click and that the data toggle allows a drop down to be displayed on click, as if I take out the data toggle it just refreshes on click, whether there is a link, javascript, etc

Comment: I see it there now. There is a hidden redirect and that cancels out all your script. What is the second action you are trying to add?

Comment: I want the drop down to work if the screen is above Xpx, otherwise if the screen is smaller then redirect to https://www.example.com

Comment: It looks like the toggle hits the form action and from there it redirects home. There is a couple of options you can do but it depends if you want to mess with the core code of OC.

Comment: in `/catalog/view/javascript/common.js` the line 26 is where the dropdown is prevented. So you can take it from there

Comment: @Grasper I've found a solution that seems to work? By work it is doing what I intended but not sure how well, seems ok on desktop and my phone let me know what your opinion is: I have changed the button with data toggle dropdown to display only on desktop in css and added another button to display on mobile with data toggle = "tab" (which I'm not sure of tabs actual use) and I've added onclick="location.href = ' xxx ';" to this button. What do you think?

Comment: if it works all is good! :-)